# droppable out event: How to get element where mouse moves to

Tags: jquery-ui, events, drag-and-drop

During droppable out event, I need the element the mouse cursor moves to. If this element is not droppable, a default behaviour should be executed.

I tried the following:

```
            $(dropSelector).droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.css("cursor", "copy");
                // Some code on drop enter here...
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                // New element: mouse pointer might move to another droppable element...
                // How to obtain the element where the mouse moves to?
                if (/* next element is NOT droppable*/) {
                    ui.helper.css("cursor", "no-drop");
                    // Some code on drop out here...
                }
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                // handle drop event
            }
        });
```

However, I could not find a way to get the element where the mouse cursor moves to during `out` event.. I tried `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` but they are not the elements I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different solution. Obviously the `over` event for the next element fires before the `out` event of the old element. So I check if the out target is the last element entered.

```
    var _target = null;
    $(dropSelector).droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
            _target = event.target;
            ui.helper.css("cursor", "copy");
            // Some code on drop enter here...
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            if (_target === event.target) {
                // No 'over' occurred for a new element
                ui.helper.css("cursor", "no-drop");
                // Some code on drop out here...
            }
            else {
               // Some code on drop out of old element

               // Perhaps some code on 'over' that has to be done after
               // drop out of old element
            }

        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            // handle drop event
        }
    });
```

**But:** Can I rely on the fact that `over` on next element fires before `out` on old element?